# C Language Cat Program that Opens File from User Input

Tags: c, linux, file, unix, cat

Basically this program is trying to implement a simple C version of the UNIX cat command. It will only display one file and if done correctly it should be able to execute on the command line with a single command line argument consisting of the name of what needs to be displayed. Some of the questions I have tried to look at as a reference are "How to continuously write to a file with user input? C language", "Create File From User Input", and "Fully opening a file in c language". These, however, did not help me very much since one wanted to open a file when it was selected with a cursor, the other was in another language, and the final one was a bit hard to follow since I'm not at that level yet. Below is my code thus far and if you all are able to lend me any advice I'd greatly appreciate it!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_LEN 30

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    File *stream;
    char filename[MAX_LEN];

    printf("File Name: ");
    scanf("%s", filename);
    stream = fopen(filename, "r");

    while(1)
    {
        fgets(stream);
        if(!feof(stream))
        {
            printf("%s", "The file you entered could not be opened\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("To continue press a key...\n");
    getchar();
    fclose(stream);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your program doesn't display the file, and it does error checking in the wrong way and in the wrong order, and you don't really have a question in your question. And if you have looked at other similar questions, the *link* to them instead of just writing their titles. And please take some time to [take the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The filename should be `argv[1]` and you need to check that `argc` is 2

Comment: Read http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/

Comment: BTW, compile with all warnings & debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`

Comment: I don't think that code even compiles. Try to get it to compile, and be warning free (use `-Wall -Wextra` to enable warnings). Or if you can't get it to compile, you can ask about the errors you can't fix. Also, read the documentation for the functions you use (like `fgets`). Also, it's good idea to check the return values for errors, it'll help a lot to find out when code compiles and runs but doesn't do the right thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your aim is to re-code the cat function under Linux, this code serve your purpose using open, close and read system calls under Linux.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 50

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int   file;
  char  buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
  int   read_size;

  if (argc < 2)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Error: usage: ./cat filename\n");
      return (-1);
    }
  file = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
  if (file == -1)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s: file not found\n", argv[1]);
      return (-1);
    }
  while ((read_size = read(file, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0)
    write(1, &buffer, read_size);

  close(file);
  return (0);
}
```

In this piece of code, you can see that error checking is done by verifying that system calls won't return -1 (under linux, system calls usually return -1 in case of error).

Hope it can help you

Comment: Don't mix `char` buffers and strings, they are totally different things.

Comment: @basile, could you please explain me my error to help me avoiding it in the future ?

Comment: `memset` is not needed here.

Comment: Is it not cleaner to memset the buffer the first time before use it ? Indeed the second is not needed I will edit my answer

Comment: No, it is just meaningless. You are not going to access any of the zeroed bytes.

Comment: You don't want `BUFFER_SIZE - 1`, it is meaningless too. If you want to read `BUFFER_SIZE - 1` bytes, why would you need a `BUFFER_SIZE`-sized buffer? What is the extra byte for? There is no null termination for buffers, they are not strings.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Telling someone to read an entire book is not very helpful.  Which section or pages?  And where do you see strings and char buffers being mixed?  All I see are blocks of binary data being read and printed to standard out.  Perhaps the code has changed and the original problem isn't there anymore, but a better reference would still be nice.  Thanks!

Comment: @jsakmeister: I believe that the OP, need most of the knowledge in that book; and yes, he need to spend a few weeks in learning